# I need a more efficient way to submit my multi-selected checkbox form to my db

Tags: php, html, mysql, post, bootstrap-4

I need a more efficient way to submit my multi-selected checkbox form to my db. Just focusing on the Vase Holes Value Checkbox, I currently have 3 separate rows/columns in my database table called "vase_holes_left" "vase_holes_centre" "vase_holes_right". Could the values go to 1 row somehow? many thanks.
Sorry i don't post here much if anymore info is needed please let me know.

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>


<?php

//Include functions
include('includes/functions.php');



?>



<?php
/************** Register new client ******************/


//require database class files
require('includes/pdocon.php');



//instatiating our database objects
$db = new Pdocon;


//Collect and clean values from the form
if (isset($_POST['submit_client'])) {

  $raw_deceased                    = cleandata($_POST['deceased']);
  $raw_cemetery                    = cleandata($_POST['cemetery']);
  $raw_plot                        = cleandata($_POST['plot']);
  $raw_jobtype                     = cleandata($_POST['jobtype']);
  $raw_stone_headstone_description = cleandata($_POST['stone_headstone_description']);
  $raw_headstone_colour            = cleandata($_POST['headstone_colour']);
  $raw_headstone_size              = cleandata($_POST['headstone_size']);
  $raw_step_base_size              = cleandata($_POST['step_base_size']);
  $raw_step_base_dowells           = cleandata($_POST['step_base_dowells']);
  $raw_base_colour                 = cleandata($_POST['base_colour']);
  $raw_base_size                   = cleandata($_POST['base_size']);
  $raw_base_dowells                = cleandata($_POST['base_dowells']);
  $raw_vase_colour                 = cleandata($_POST['vase_colour']);
  $raw_vase_style                  = cleandata($_POST['vase_style']);
  $raw_vase_number                 = cleandata($_POST['vase_number']);
  $raw_vase_holes_left             = cleandata($_POST['vase_holes_left']);
  $raw_vase_holes_centre           = cleandata($_POST['vase_holes_centre']);
  $raw_vase_holes_right            = cleandata($_POST['vase_holes_right']);


  $c_deceased                      = sanitize($raw_deceased);
  $c_cemetery                      = sanitize($raw_cemetery);
  $c_plot                          = sanitize($raw_plot);
  $c_jobtype                       = sanitize($raw_jobtype);
  $c_stone_headstone_description   = sanitize($raw_stone_headstone_description);
  $c_headstone_colour              = sanitize($raw_headstone_colour);
  $c_headstone_size                = sanitize($raw_headstone_size);
  $c_step_base_size                = sanitize($raw_step_base_size);
  $c_step_base_dowells             = sanitize($raw_step_base_dowells);
  $c_base_colour                   = sanitize($raw_base_colour);
  $c_base_size                     = sanitize($raw_base_size);
  $c_base_dowells                  = sanitize($raw_base_dowells);
  $c_vase_colour                   = sanitize($raw_vase_colour);
  $c_vase_style                    = sanitize($raw_vase_style);
  $c_vase_number                   = sanitize($raw_vase_number);
  $c_vase_holes_left               = sanitize($raw_vase_holes_left);
  $c_vase_holes_centre             = sanitize($raw_vase_holes_centre);
  $c_vase_holes_right              = sanitize($raw_vase_holes_right);

  $db->query('SELECT * FROM  clients WHERE deceased=:deceased');

  $db->bindValue(':deceased', $c_deceased, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  $row = $db->fetchSingle();

  if ($row) {

    redirect('clients.php');

    keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                      <strong>Sorry!</strong> Client Already Exist. Please Register Again
                </div>');
  } else {

    $db->query("INSERT INTO clients (id, jobtype, deceased, plot, cemetery, stone_headstone_description, headstone_colour, headstone_size, step_base_size, step_base_dowells, base_colour, base_size, base_dowells, vase_colour, vase_style, vase_number, vase_holes_left, vase_holes_centre, vase_holes_right ) VALUES (NULL, :jobtype, :deceased, :plot, :cemetery, :stone_headstone_description, :headstone_colour, :headstone_size, :step_base_size, :step_base_dowells, :base_colour, :base_size, :base_dowells, :vase_colour, :vase_style, :vase_number, :vase_holes_left, :vase_holes_centre, :vase_holes_right ) ");


    $db->bindValue(':jobtype',                                    $c_jobtype, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':deceased',                                   $c_deceased, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':plot',                                       $c_plot, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':cemetery',                                   $c_cemetery, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':stone_headstone_description',                $c_stone_headstone_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':headstone_colour',                           $c_headstone_colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':headstone_size',                             $c_headstone_size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':step_base_size',                             $c_step_base_size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':step_base_dowells',                          $c_step_base_dowells, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':base_colour',                                $c_base_colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':base_size',                                  $c_base_size, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':base_dowells',                               $c_base_dowells, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_colour',                                $c_vase_colour, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_style',                                 $c_vase_style, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_number',                                $c_vase_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_holes_left',                            $c_vase_holes_left, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_holes_centre',                          $c_vase_holes_centre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $db->bindValue(':vase_holes_right',                           $c_vase_holes_right, PDO::PARAM_STR);



    $run_client = $db->execute();

    if ($run_client) {

      redirect('clients.php');

      keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                  <strong>Success!</strong> Client registered successfully.
            </div>');
    } else {

      keepmsg('<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                  <strong>Sorry!</strong> Client could not be registered.
            </div>');
    }
  }
}

?>



 <div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes_left" id="vase_holes_left" value="vase_holes_left">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_left">Left</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes_centre" id="vase_holes_centre" value="vase_holes_centre">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_centre">Centre</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes_right" id="vase_holes_right" value="vase_holes_right">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_right">Right</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if user b INSERTS *while* user a is SELECTING?

Comment: I was thinking of also adding "required" to at least one checkbox selection, somehow, maybe using a php else statement?

Comment: The Form is working as it is, so another alternative is when the data gets echoed to the client data display page i could just echo all 3 vase selections into one html table cell?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly.

Group all 3 fields with same name="vase_holes" put only one required that will force user to pick one of them with HTML.

Make a new column vase_holes in your database and store this 3 values: vase_holes_left, vase_holes_centre, vase_holes_right.

Now you have one column with 3 types of data and you can filter your future quarry's based on that.

This is all assuming there can be one value. If you want more values in same row, join them with PHP implode option and store it into one row. You can devide it with / for example so later if you need to separate it you can do explode on /.

This will minimize your input into one column, one row per submitting.

```html
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes" id="vase_holes_left" value="vase_holes_left" required
>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_left">Left</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes" id="vase_holes_centre" value="vase_holes_centre">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_centre">Centre</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="vase_holes" id="vase_holes_right" value="vase_holes_right">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="vase_holes_right">Right</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to select all or some. and yes if none are selected the "required" is best. Thank you.